# Unable to debug the sitemap error

Tags: xml, sitemap

I'm trying to pull data from my database and use them in xml files to generate a sitemap. I want 10 files to be generated in compressed format each containing 10 links.That is, file1 contains 1-10 id's , file2 contains 11-20 id's,......file10 contains 91-100 id's. Below is my code to do that -

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
$mysql_con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "cases");
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM samplecases LIMIT " . 10*($i-1) . ", 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql_con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $url = $xml->addChild('url');
            $url->addChild('loc', "http://legalcrystal.com/cases/" .$row['id']. "/" . $row['casename']);
            $url->addChild('lastmod',  $row['decidedon']);
    }
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    $dom->save('/var/www/html/es/sitemap/case-'.$i .'.xml');
    $file = "/var/www/html/es/sitemap/case-".$i .".xml";
    $gzfile = "/var/www/html/es/sitemap/case-" .$i .".gz";
    $fp = gzopen ($gzfile, 'w9');
    gzwrite ($fp, file_get_contents($file));
    gzclose($fp);
    unlink($file);
}
?>
```

The problem is, when I run the code I get the following error -

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 44 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

And only first 10 id's are selected and are not printed in xml format.Later when I look at .gz files, file1 contains 1-10 id's, file2 contains 1-20 id's which it was suppose to contain 11-20 id's.........file10 contains 1-100 records, it was suppose to contain 91-100 id's.

Also when I comment out the line `Header('Content-type: text/xml')` I get all the id's printed in an unformatted way, in a single line.
Can someone please help me overcome these 2 bugs?

Comment: Why are you generating a (simple) XML DOM, rendering it to a plain XML string, and loading that string again into a DOM? Seems overkill.

Comment: I'm still a beginner. Can you please be more precise. It would help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved the id's getting repeated in every file. Just added `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>')` line inside for loop.